# How to run the test project to test another application using JUnit?

Tags: android, junit

I've got this peculiar issue while testing for an android project via a test project.
The test project runs on the emulator but does not run on the device. It shows the following error on the device:

```
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
    at o rg.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 17 more"
```

Why do I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`?

Comment: How do you run the test project on the device? Are you sure your device uses recent enough sdk? (compare Android versions)

Comment: are you sure that your test classes are in the classpath of whatever you are running on the device?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: I'm working on linux so i downloaded the file from the only link available on [developer.android.com].

Comment: @oers: yes i've specified the classpath in the test project.

Comment: @Puneeth You actually did not answer any of my questions. First of all check the android version on the device: Settings -> About Phone -> Adnroid Version. Also tell us exactly how do you run the tests: using adb, Eclipse or just trying to double click on the installed test app.